# Compose one image from multiple images in asp.net and crop them

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, drawimage

I am making a system for compositioning an image from multiple images. Let's say I have two images and I want to compose an image like this one :

[image]

The thick border defines the complete image that I want. It is a div with the resolution of `600X540` and inside of it two divs, each one containing a different image that I can position as I want. At the end of the positioning, I get the left and top borders of each image (corresponding to the whole div).

I'm having trouble creating the image in code behind. I'm using the `Bitmap.DrawImage` Method. Here is my code :

```
 oImgOut = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(600, 540)

 oGraph = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(oImgOut)
 oGraph.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
 oGraph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
 oGraph.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
 oGraph.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
 oGraph.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.White, 0, 0, 600, 540)

 //image 1
 oGraph.DrawImage(oImg1, CInt(left1), CInt(top1), CInt(width1), CInt(height1))
 oImg1.Dispose()

 //image2
 oGraph.DrawImage(oImg2, CInt(left2), CInt(top2), CInt(width2), CInt(height2))
 oImg2.Dispose()

 oImgOut.Save(strDirectory)
 oImgOut.Dispose()
```

This is what I have got so far :

[image]

I tried to give each image a width of 300px and height of 540px, but as you see the image on the right looks ugly :

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to crop the image? I looked over most of the `DrawImage` prototypes but I couldn't find any that do the job I want. Surely you'll know better than me.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for cropping images with the DrawImage function

```
 oGraph.DrawImage(oImg2, CInt(left2), CInt(top2), _
                            New Rectangle(0, 0, _
                                          If(CInt(width2) > 600, 600, CInt(width2)), _
                                          If(CInt(height2) > 270, 270, CInt(height2)) + CInt(top2) _
                                           ), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

but i don't understand how it works, please guys i need your help :( .